# Xcode could not index the header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, symbol-not-found

When I used Xcode 6 to develop an iOS app, I found Xcode cannot index names when I set up a separate header file.

The detailed situation is like this:

I set up a separate header file named `TestClass.h`, and imported `Foundation/Foundation.h`. However, no auto completion when I tried to enter `NSObject`, and when I press COMMAND and click `Foundation/Foundation.h`, "Symbol not found" appears.

I have tried to delete the derived data and re-open Xcode, but it did not help.

Is there any solution to this problem?